# Using input type file in the anchor tag for a dropdown-item

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use the input type file in one of my drop down item which is in the anchor tag.

So, Here my code is like ,

```
 <div className="dropdown-menu actions-text">
     <a className="dropdown-item" href="#" onClick={e => props.viewJob(e, item.id, item.jdName)}>
         <i className="fa fa-envelope mr-2 view-icon" />
         View JD
     </a>
     <a className="dropdown-item" href='#'>
         <i className="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2 upload-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
         Upload Resume
     </a>
     <input type='file' title="" onChange={(e) => { props.uploadResumeFolder(e, item.id, item.jdName) }}
            directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="" allowdirs="" multiple />
     <a className="dropdown-item" href="#"><i className="fa fa-download mr-2 download-icon" aria-hidden="true" />
         Download Tracker</a>
</div>
```

but here if I add one more option at the top then the next one is getting clicked for that file option. always taking the second one by default.

So, How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Have you tried hiding your `input`, adding `id` to it, and then adding an inline `onClick` event  on your `a` tag to programatically click the `input` through its `id`?

Comment: No I have not tried that

Comment: Sorry, I believe hiding the input is not necessary assuming that the classNames are handling which to show. But do try the inline onClick on the anchor tag that you wish to trigger the file input.

Comment: So you are saying onChange={(e) => { props.uploadResumeFolder(e, item.id, item.jdName) }}  this on the a tag itself instead of the input type

Comment: No. just trigger a click event to the `input` tag inside the onClick event in your `a` tag. Well actually, I can't see how the input is clicked through the `a` tag in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something similar to this?

```
<a href="#" onClick="(function(e){
    console.log('clicking', e);
    document.getElementById('X1').click();
})();">click here</a>

<input hidden type='file' title="" onChange="(function(e){
    console.log('changed file input', e)
})();" id="X1" />
```

Comment: No actually I am using a react for this not a plain javascript